# Enchanting with the Black Star

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can the Black Star be used repeatedly to enchant items? Assuming of course that it is re-filled with a soul between applying enchantments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Yes it can.

That's kind of the point.

Comment: Yeah, that makes it awesome. Alternatively it could have only been useable for recharging enchanted weapons, in which case it is still useful, but much less so.

Comment: That's actually a great way to raise the Enchanting skill, if you use soul trap enchanted weapons to kill things and refill the weapon used after every kill/soul trapped in the Black Star. That's if you don't have the unofficial patch, which "fixes" the Black Star. It helps of course when raising Enchanting to have the Mage Stone active and at least a  simple rested bonus. It makes this method considerably faster.